# How to program a circle of radius r and center x,y with annotation box positioned bottom,left of x,y using PURE PDF 1.7 specification

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

I am looking for a way to draw a dot (or small circle) that is an internal "annotation" link to a popup box in a PDF using specification 1.7...

TCPDF does this internally, with code like...  see:  https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_036/

```
    2 0 obj
<< /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 3 0 R /F2 4 0 R /F3 6 0 R >> /XObject << /XT5 5 0 R /I0 11 0 R >> >>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type /Annot /Subtype /Text /Rect [235.275591 737.008110 263.622047 765.354567] /Contents (þÿ
```

I am looking for a solution that does this directly.  That is, explaining how the PDF language creates the trigger object (e.g., the circle), and the annotation object (e.g., the popup box), and how the internal linking works.

Comment: Do you want the circle to be drawn by an annotation or by the page content?

Comment: @mkl  The circle is the main page content, which triggers a regular box-like annotation.

Comment: If the circle is part of the page content, then it does not trigger anything. The page content is static (OCGs aside) and insensitive. The area, though, which triggers the popup, may well coincide with that circle.

Comment: @mkl okay if that is a requirement.